# Why the BLE device receive the wrong value in C?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to development in BLE. The **device-A** will send the `0` or `1` to **device-B**.

I have defined a `struct` for **device-A** like the following.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t                    handle;                     /**< Attribute handle */
    uint16_t                    offset;                     /**< Attribute value offset, ignored if not needed for a command */
    uint16_t                    len;                        /**< Length of attribute value */
    wiced_bt_gatt_auth_req_t    auth_req;                   /**< Authentication requirement (see @link wiced_bt_gatt_auth_req_e wiced_bt_gatt_auth_req_t @endlink) */
    int32_t                     value[1];                   /**< The attribute value (actual length is specified by 'len') */
    //uint16_t                     value[1];                   /**< The attribute value (actual length is specified by 'len') */
} wiced_bt_gatt_value_t;
```

And in **device-A** , it sends data to the **device-B** by following code:

```
wiced_bt_gatt_value_t write_value;

write_value.handle = proximity_service[SERVICE_Hello].attribute_value_handle; // Handle of Immediate Alert service's alert level handle
write_value.len = 1; // Length of immediate alert level value
write_value.value[0] = new_proximity_alert_level; // Set alert level to 2
write_value.auth_req = GATT_AUTH_REQ_NONE; // No authentication requested
wiced_bt_gatt_send_write (connection_id, GATT_WRITE_NO_RSP, &write_value);
```

In the above code, the **device-A** send **`1`** to the **device-B**.

The data is received at the **device-B**, but the value is **`08`** and it also shows **`33568264`**.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question correctly, but maybe it's something with the endianness.

Comment: I think it may be endianness too, but if the attribute is actually "len = 1" and it's only one byte, then endianness shouldn't enter in to the issue.  Does Broadcom provide a forum for wiced developers?  Maybe you should post there.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have declared `int32_t value[1];` in `struct` instead of `int32_t value;`? Whats the data type of `new_proximity_alert_level` ?